# React Navigation v5 send params from screen to stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have my `Screen` and my `Stack`

In my screen I am doing some computations which i need to use on the options, where I style the screen, nothing too big, just some booleans. How can I pass the properties from the Screen to the Stack, I know you do it via `route.params` but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried the following

in my screen:
`navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ isValidForm }));` as some part of the docs say.

I also tried `navigation.setParams({ isValidForm });`,

Then in my header:

```
const Stack = () => {
  console.log(route.params) //no trace of it here
  return (
    <Stack.Screen screen={MyScreen} name={MyScreen}
       options={{
         headerLeft: () =>
          <NavigationHeader.TextButton
            disabled={!route.params?.isValidForm}
          />
       }}
     />
  );
}
```

But none of them show up when I log my `route.params` in my stack. Any ideeas?

Comment: Set params expects a key-value pair. Did you try `...setParams({ isValidForm: true })`?

Comment: Yeah, i'm actually taking the `isValidForm` as an argument so it would translate to `{isValidForm: true}`